# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType next]: unrecognized selector sent to instance '

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType next]: unrecognized selector sent to instance '
this error is occuring because this line "[self autorelease];"
if i comment this line then the exception not come but app looks very slow,so please tell me that what could i wrote the line that instead of that line

> ```
> if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
> {                
>      pagestr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)];
>      //dateLabel.text=previousDate;
>      //textView.text=pagestr;
>      EditorPage* prev= [[EditorPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditorPage" bundle:nil];
>      prev.dateString= previousDate;
>      prev.bodyString= pagestr;
>      NSArray* array= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:prev,@"forward",nil];
>      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"next EditorPage" object:array];
>      [prev autorelease];
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When do you do `[ self autorelease ]`? I think that's very unusual--it's probably incorrect.

This message means you are sending the message *next* to an object of `NSCFType`.

Messages like this are often caused by sending a message to an object that has been release and whose memory was subsequently reallocated to a different type of object.

You can turn on zombies to track down this kind of issue. **Also, you could move your code to ARC to help avoid retain/release issues.**

Comment: if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
   {                
    pagestr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)];
                
//    dateLabel.text=previousDate;
//    textView.text=pagestr;
    EditorPage* prev= [[EditorPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditorPage" bundle:nil];
    prev.dateString= previousDate;
    prev.bodyString= pagestr;
    NSArray* array= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:prev,@"previous",nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"next EditorPage" object:array];
    [self autorelease];
   }

Comment: you should add that to your question, not as a comment--this isn't really readable.

Comment: but i m unable to post code in question thats y i post it here.please help me if you can

Comment: don't call `[ self autorelease ]`!

Comment: You should switch your project to ARC!